# Disable Touch Bar completely on MacBook Pro 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

The Touch Bar on my MacBook Pro 2020 flickers a lot, and due to that I want completely turn it off, as in not using it at all! All solutions I have found so far were just using the bar for the function keys but I want to switch it off completely. Is that possible through a script or something? If yes, does anyone knows how to implement it? The difference between my question and others is that my MacBook model has an actual physical escape key which means the Touch Bar is not needed at all.

To fix the flickering itself, I tried the touchbar_deflicker script which restarts the Touch Bar every 2 mins so it doesn't sleep, that didn't help. I also tried formatting the MacBook as the Apple Genius Bar said it might be a software issue and that usually fixes it. That didn't work as well.

Comment: If you have 'formatted' (presumably erasing and reinstalling the OS), and the problem still persists, then that would point to hardware, rather than software. A software issue would likely be reported by many other users with similar configs.

Comment: The drivers (kexts) for the touch bar are on the secure side of macOS (can’t be written to) so this ball is totally in Apple’s court.  Booting to Safe Mode would eliminate any “software” conflicts.  Given that you reinstalled macOS, the issue is hardware.  Also, [Apple recently killed off the  touch bar](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/why-apple-finally-killed-the-touch-bar-in-macbook-pro/), likely because it was a flaky piece of hardware and just a PITA all around.